# How to drop a pin on Google map and how to get current address in dialog box on Google map?

Tags: android, android-maps, android-canvas, mylocationoverlay

I am working on one application which is related to Google map. I am a beginner in Google map.

I want to do an application  which shows a Pin at my Current location. When I click on that pin it shows the dialog which contain my current address. "Pin is movable". When I move the pin from one location to other on Google map the dialog box show the address of that location.

So please give me idea or reference site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch) showing one way to drag-and-drop of `OverlayItems` in an `ItemizedOverlay`.

You can try to use the [`Geocoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class to get an address given a latitude and longitude.

Note that your project is more advanced than what I would recommend for "a beginner in Google map".

Comment: @CommonsWare I am having Map in ScrollView=>LinearLayout=>MapView. Now on setDragImagePosition(x, y) pointer goes away from drop location.